# JetBrains Mono font not showing in my Android Sudio Project in font file

Tags: android-studio, fonts

I am trying to utilise JetBrains Mono font in my app and for some reason Android Studio cannot detect @font folder and neither the contents of the folder (being all variations of the JetBrains Mono font). I have tried rebuilding the project and cleaning the project but to no avail.

I get the following error messages:

1) Error mapping font file @font/JetBrainsMono-Regular.ttf

2) Exception raised during rendering (Details)

[image]